# service worker and client requests 'Cache-control': 'no-cache'

Tags: service-worker

Suppose the client does this

```
fetch('example.json', {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'Cache-control': 'no-cache'
    },
    method: 'GET'
  }).then()
```

And the server worker does this

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event:any) => {
  let request = event.request
  if (request.method !== 'GET') return
  event.respondWith( caches.match(request)
    .then( cachedResponse => {
      if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse
      return caches.open(RUNTIME)
        .then(cache => fetch(request)
            .then(response => cache.put(request, response.clone())
                .then(() => response) ))  
  }))
})
```

Can I assume `caches.match(request)` will figure out `'Cache-control': 'no-cache'` and just bail out regardless what is stored in the service worker cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to correct me but after googling some more I found this

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451664#

When I test `console.log('SW :', request.headers.get('Cache-control'))` the headers seem to be stript out.

I am slowly getting why some browser vendors are hesitant for service workers, it makes the whole caching unintuitive and browser cache already was unintuitive in the first place.

Comment: Which browser vendors do you have the impression are against service workers?

Comment: Maybe against is the wrong word i will change it to hesitant http://caniuse.com/#search=serviceworker

Comment: OK yeah I think that just indicates Microsoft and Apple have not put the resources into implementing it yet. Implementing Service Workers takes a huge amount of development effort and involves touching all the caching code spread out all over the place in the browser engine, and needs to done carefully to avoid introducing risk of security exploits. But anyway Microsoft and Apple will be implementing it all eventually

Comment: 100% agreed about Service Workers caching being unintuitive and browser caching already being unintuitive to begin with. This stuff is voodoo